# the List of Countries available

Tags: spotify, country

I'd like to get the full list of countries spotify's service available. I want to locate spotify icon on my app if my app users are in those countries.
I've checked some Web APIs, but I couldn't find the those for each tracks or albums.
I want to get the newest country-check list automatically by APIs or somehow.
If you know anything, please let me know it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to retrieve a list of all the countries where Spotify is available from the [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api), but I want to encourage you to [create a feature request in Spotify's Web API issue tracker](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/new) on Github.